# dictionary.TryGetValue vs FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, compare, tuples

According to [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270346.aspx), a Tuple objects Equals method will use the values of the two Tuple objects.

Why does the following not produce the same result:

```
[Test]
public void TestTupleWithDictionary() 
{
    Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, string> values = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, string>();

    values.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("1", "1"), "Item 1");
    values.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("1", "2"), "Item 2");

    Assert.IsNotNull(values.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == new Tuple<string, string>("1", "2")));

    string value;
    values.TryGetValue(new Tuple<string, string>("1", "2"), out value);

    Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(value);
}
```

Why does `values.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == new Tuple<string, string>("1", "2"))` return `null` where as `values.TryGetValue(new Tuple<string, string>("1", "2"), out value);` finds the correct key and returns the value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using `==`, which isn't overloaded for `Tuple<,>`, so it's using a reference identity check... and as you've constructed a new tuple, that will *never* be true.

This would be *correct*, but undesirable:

```
// Don't do this!
values.FirstOrDefault(x => new Tuple<string, string>("1", "2").Equals(x.Key))
```

That would:

- Create a new tuple on each iteration
- Have to look through every entry until it found a matching one, which is an O(N) operation... compared with the normally-O(1) operation of a dictionary lookup

Comment: How is this different than `values.TryGetValue(new Tuple<string, string>("1", "2"), out value);` As I am also constructing a new tuple

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt: That's constructing *one* new tuple, not a new one on each iteration. And `TryGetValue` will use the hash code to find the matching entry in constant time, assuming no hash collisions.